# Scope of parameters in a complex function definition

Tags: c, function, parameters, scope, language-lawyer

Consider the following obscure definition of a function returning a pointer to an array of `char`s:

```
char (*func(int var))[sizeof var]
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Is it valid?**

The questionable part is the use of the identifier `var` in the `sizeof` expression. At least according to GCC 4.9.2, `var` is not visible in the `sizeof` expression. (Note that if `var` in the sizeof expression is replaced with, say, `42`, the code is valid and this question becomes uninteresting.)

However, in the C11 specification draft n1570 (relevant parts are the same in C99, though possibly with different subclause numbering), subclause 6.2.1 discusses the scopes of identifiers, and contains the following sentences that are relevant for this case:

6.2.1p4 contains:

> If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block.

6.2.1p7 contains (bolding mine):

> Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of
>   the tag in a type specifier that declares the tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that
>   begins just after the appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any
>   other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its declarator.**

Clearly, the declarator for `var` appears inside the list of parameter declarations in the definition of a function. So according to 6.2.1p4 its scope ends at the end of the function body ("associated block"). Also, `var` clearly corresponds to "any other identifier" mentioned in 6.2.1p7, so its scope begins just after the completion of its declarator, i.e. at the end of the parameter list.

It seems to me that the specification says nothing else relevant about the scope of `var`. Given that the specification doesn't say otherwise, the obvious (to me, anyway) interpretation of the "beginning" and "end" of a scope means that the scope spans the entire lexical interval from the beginning to the end. Thus it seems that `var` should in fact be visible in the `sizeof` expression.

Is there something in the specification that I haven't accounted for?
Is the concept of the *scope of an identifier* meant to be interpreted in some other way than "the uninterrupted lexical interval from the beginning of the scope to the end of the scope"? If so, how is this apparent in the specification?

Comment: Fyi, gcc is not alone. clang 3.5 with -std=C11 reports the same error (undeclared identifier: `var`).

Answer (score 2):

The `[sizeof var]` part is simply not part of the block, nor of the declaration list, but of the return type. So the only identifiers that are visible there are those with file scope.

Comment: So you're saying that block-scope identifiers can only be visible in blocks and parameter lists of function definitions?
That seems like a reasonable behavior, but I'm unable to deduce that from the spec.
From the spec, the understanding I get about identifier scopes is that they begin at one point and end at another,
and are visible everywhere inbetween (except when shadowed by another declaration). And `var`'s scope
begins after its declarator and ends at the end of `func`'s body. I can't see anything in the spec that would imply
that it's not visible outside the param list and body.

Comment: @SirDayBat, because it part of the return type then would have file scope, no?

Comment: @JensGustedt, if some identifier was declared in the sizeof expression, then that identifier would have file scope, yes. But otherwise there's no scope associated with an expression that doesn't declare anything. But still, I don't see what (in the specification) would prevent a declaration with file scope from referring to things with block scope. I hope I'm not misunderstanding what you're saying. In any case, can you refer to relevant parts of the spec that would support this answer?

Comment: I am saying that you would be *using* the identifier in an expression that is part of a file scope declaration, namely the return type of the function. If that would be so, that identifier would have to be a valid identifier in that scope, which it isn't, it has block scope.

Comment: I think I see your point. But does the specification
really say that? That a block-scope identifier cannot be
used in a file-scope declaration? If I understand
the specification right, it's not as if scopes are 
separate name spaces or anything - after all, file-scope 
identifiers can be used in blocks, etc. To my knowledge,
the spec doesn't ban the reverse either. The _type_ of the scope (file, block, etc.) doesn't, in itself, have effect on where the identifier is visible - only the beginning and end of the scope do.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of a function is defined in the block scope or file scope where the function itself  is declared. It does not belong to the outer-most block scope of the function definition.
In this scope (where the function is declared) parameters of the function are not yet declared.

You can consider the function definition like

```
return type: char ( * )[sizeof var] // Oops..What is var?!
{
   // function block scope including its parameters declarations;
   int var;
}
```

Comment: Similarly to how I commented to Jens - this seems like a reasonable behavior but I can't seem to arrive at this conclusion (or contradict the conclusion I presented in the question) from the specification.

Comment: @SirDayBat Function parameters either have function prototype scope or the function outermost block scope. Return type is not a function parameter.

Comment: @SirDayBat It makes sense to define separate scope for function parameters because the same parameter name can be used in declarations and definitions of many functions. Return types do not have their own special scope.

Comment: True, a function parameter (in a function definition) has a scope that begins after its declarator and continues throughout the function's outermost block. And I claim that the spec does _not_ say that the scope is temporarily terminated for the remainder of the function's declarator. Regarding the code in this answer: if return types were declared that way in C, then `var` indeed wouldn't be visible. But as it stands, with C's syntax, the `sizeof` expression comes lexically after the declaration of `var` (and before the end of `var`'s scope), which should be all that matters.

Comment: @  SirDayBat  In my opiniom this quote of the standard is clear "If the declarator or type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the associated block." It says about declarators of the list of parameter declarations. The declarator of the function itself does not belong to the parameter list.

Comment: That's true, but I don't see why it would matter - the function's name (`func`) is not referred to anywhere, so the scope of the identifier `func` doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @SirDayBat Function name has type. Moreover you could define the return type using a typedef. For example typedef char ( *return_type )[sizeof var ]; And what is var in this case? If a parameter has an internal scope relative to the function declaration itslef then it is not visible yet.

Comment: Just because the return type can't, in this case, be defined with a `typedef`, IMO isn't a reason why it couldn't be defined in the non-typedef version. _"If a parameter has an internal scope relative to the function declaration itslef then it is not visible yet."_ Does the C specification actually say that? If so, do you know where? If it doesn't say that, do you think it's a defect in the spec, or do you consider this too obvious to require an explicit mention in the specification?

Comment: @SirDayBat  C Standard says that only parameters have internal scope relative to the function declaration. It is enough, The function declaration itself relative to its block scope is in the outer scope. Otherwise neither function declaration would be visible. Also it is useful to consider how unqualified name lookup is performed in C++. There is also only parameters of class member function are looked-up in the class scope. The return type is searched in block scope or name space where the class is defined.

Comment: @SirDayBat  Take into account that C has also identifier list that is declared after the usual form of the function declaration. So the function declarator includes only types of parameters but the parameters as objects are defined only in the outer scope of the function itself.